# JavaFX Iterate through TableView cells (row wise) and set background color

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have 31 columns(day 1-day 31) and 12(monthnames) rows on my tableview. I want to search complete table (**row wise search**) for a data(day) and need to set a background color only for that matching cell.I could see that it is possible to set background color for a cell in a particular column using cellfactory function.

```
  birthdayColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<Person, LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                  if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } 

            // Style all dates in March with a different color.
            if (item. == Month.MARCH) {
                setTextFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
            } else {
                setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                setStyle("");
            }
       };
    });
```

Here it checking only one column named 'birthdayColumn'.But in my case it should check all the table cells(rowwise) in one single method  and need to set a background color only for that matching cell.How i can do that.Thank you in advance

Comment: A `TableView` really doesn't seem well suited to a calendar display like this. It would probably be better just to use a `GridPane` and manage the cells yourself. I don't really understand how things are set up here: which column is the `birthdayColumn`? I would imagine having 31 table columns which were essentially all the same. And why is the data model for the rows called `Person`??? Surely `Month` would be a better name (you could perhaps use `java.time.Month`, depending on how you manage the data). If you really want to use a `TableView`, you need to show more how you have set things up.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    LocalDate myBirthday = null; //initialize with the date you need to highlight

    birthdayColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<Person, LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } 
                else {
                    setText(item.toString());
                    setGraphic(null);

                    if (item.equals(myBirthday)) {
                        setTextFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                    }
                    else {
                        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                        setStyle("");
                    }
                }
            }};
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort,but i want row wise search.Not a single column search.Here it searching only a single column

Comment: you have to set the same cellfactory for all columns, as cell factories are assigned per column, not per row

Comment: Oh my god.So should i set it for all the 31 columns.But is there any other method without using cellfactory to find matching cell value?

Comment: @ShareefAzeez You're presumably already creating the columns in a loop, right? Just place the code to set the cell factory inside the same loop. It is not really a big deal.

Comment: Ok i got it.Consider i want to search only on first cell of the all column means how i can modify the above code?

Comment: use this.getTableRow().getIndex() in the updateItem() method, if the index is zero, you are in the first cell of the column